# Replay a vim macro until specified line number

Tags: normal-mode, repeated-commands

Suppose caret is on the line `10` and I've recorded macros `@d`.

I need to replay macros until line 25. If I know that macros move caret one line per execution, I can calculate that it should be executed `25 - 10 = 15` times.

So the command will be `15@d`.

But is it possible to use something like 'until line':

```
:15@d
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use this for specific line

```
:10,15 norm! @d
```

If you want something like `until line`, you can use this instead

```
:.,15 norm! @d
```

Or a more visual way, by selecting the lines you want to change via Visual mode and then execute the command

```
:norm! @d
```

**EDIT!**

You can also use `15:` from normal mode to execute the macro for the next 15 lines

```
15: norm! @d
```

Thanks for @dedowsdi for the tip :D

References:

[:h range](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:range)

[:h normal](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/390194/9605555/

Comment: You can omit `norm!`, you can also use `15:` from normal mode to do it quickly.

Comment: @dedowsdi im not aware that you can omit norm! here—macro replay is a normal command...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You are right, sorry for the noise.

Comment: @dedowsdi Thanks for the `15:` tip. Adding it to my answers :D